# React Native: Do changes in Context API values called via useContext hook always cause re-renders of the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

Here is the situation:

1. I have a component (ListItem.js) that show the information about another user, and a button to recommend that user.
2. The component is designed such that there is a button reflecting the recommendation status, and when it is clicked, it recommends/remove from recommendation according to the status, just like 'Like/Unlike' in Facebook.
3. I am using Context API, which retrieves information about the other users that the user has recommended, and stores the value.
4. Using useContext hook, I call the context API value to ListItem.js component so that I can achive #2.
5. ListItem.js is rendered as an item under a FlatList component, i.e. there are many ListItem components rendered on the screen.

The problem is that when I click on one of the ListItems' buttons, it re-renders all of the components, not just one, whereas I'd like only the specific child component to re-render. This is understandably detrimental to user experience.

Below is the simplified code for ListItem.js:

```
function ListItem(item) {

    const { recolist, setRecolist } = useContext(Recolist);

    const recopush = () => {
        /*
        Function to update the database
        */
    
    //The Context API is defined at App.js, and listens to the recolist value so that when it is set to null, it will refresh and update the value
        setRecolist(null);
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{item.item.username}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={recopush}>
                <Text>
                    {recolist.includes(item.item.postid)?
                    'recommended':
                    'recommend'
                    }    
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

export default ListItem;
```

Here are my questions:

1. Will any update to the Context API value re-render the component, regardless of where it was triggered?
2. If so, what might be the workaround to prevent this from happening? i.e. to make sure that only the specific component re-renders?

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: When a React component rerenders, it also rerenders its entire subtree. This is necessary for reconciliation. You should note that this rendering occurs during the "render phase" for diffing purposes and is generally quite fast, and then there is rendering during the "commit phase" where computed changes are committed to the DOM, this part is slow/expensive, so it's why React has optimized it as much as it can. Are you seeing an actual performance issue? How are you determining "rerenders"? If you've not an issue then don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: In other words, make sure you're not doing something weird like console logging in the body of a component or any other unintentional side-effect, and try to do some performance auditing in the browser to see if and how your app performs. Try to get some *actual* metrics.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, thanks for the comment and advice. The reason I'd like to prevent rerendering is that the component in question actually has pictures of the users, just like 'suggested friends' in Facebook. So, when a user clicks on a 'recommend' button, I'd like only that child component to re-render, but all of the child components under the FlatList component rerender, causing unnecessary flickers in the entire screen. It's not about performance, it is about user experience in this case.

Comment: This may be more an issue what the list components do when they are rerendered. Can you share a more comprehensive code example for both the item components and how they are rendered? You could try wrapping them in the `memo` HOC and pass a custom `areEqual` function.